# How to check if server connection exists?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, server

In my app I have asyncTask classes, that connects to a local/remote server to get some data, I want to check the server connection before the asyncTask runs,
I have this function:

```
public static boolean checkServerAvailable(String hostURL) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(hostURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("" + code);
        return true;
        // You can determine on HTTP return code received. 200 is success.
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

This function uses timeout to connect to server, and if the timeout expires it means that there is no server. The problem is that I'm run this code and it's returning  "there is no server" even if the server exists.

I've tried to set a big timeout like 5000ms but it pauses the UI very long time, and sometimes still returns "there is no server" even when the server is exist.

what can I do?
Thank you!

Comment: May be there is an issue of your internet connection.

Comment: Which of these three catch blocks does it enter, and what exception does it throw?

Comment: `it's returning "there is no server" `. Impossible. That function returns true or false.

Comment: yes but I called to this function from another function, that returns a String.

Comment: It enter to the IOException, and prints "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.0.6 (port 8080) after 5000ms"

Comment: Where is your app runnning on?

Comment: The app is running on the local server, and the finished method are pushed to the remote server.

Comment: On the local server? On your pc? Apps cannot run on pcs. Only on Android devices or in an Android emulator program. The emulator runs on a pc.

Comment: So you have two servers? For what?

Comment: One to the developers and one to the App review.

Comment: This answer does not help to solve your problem. Be a little more to the point please. And answer ALL questions and remarks if you want help.

Comment: The app is running on Android phone (Galaxy s3), I said the servers bucause my question was about the server. So I didn't understand you correctley.

Comment: You also said that the app was running on the local server. So is your phone the local server?

Comment: No the pc is the local server, I check the server connection by stop the running of my server project, I have two projects one is the android app, and second is the local server.

Answer (score 0):

> check the server connection before the asyncTask runs

Then you have to do that in another AsyncTask.

So this all makes little sense.

You are not using `StrictMode` is it?

Comment: what is it StrictMode ?

Comment: Please react on the needed extra AsyncTask.

Comment: Do you want that I will add the asyncTask to the question?

Comment: No. I wanted to know if you had that code already in an AsyncTask or thread. Or not.

Comment: Checking the server connection of course. That was your problem isnt it?

Comment: I'm a beginner developer in android can you explain me more about your solution please?

Comment: You should just answer my question first. That's all. Repeat: are you calling or executing  checkServerAvailable(String hostURL) in the doInBackground of an AsyncTask?

Comment: Yes, but the timeout is expires before the app connects to the server.

Comment: Well why did you not say right away that you had it already in an async task? Would have saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score -1):

try using socket here is example code

```
    Socket socket;
    final String host = "your.server.IP.or.host";
    final int port = 80;
    final int timeout = 5000;   // 5 seconds or what ever time you want 

    try {
      socket = new Socket();
      socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
      Log.e("ServerSock", "I couldn't resolve the host you've provided!");
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
      Log.e("ServerSock", "After a reasonable amount of time, I'm not able to connect, Server is probably down!");
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
      Log.e("ServerSock", "Hmmm... Sudden disconnection, probably you should start again!");
    }
```

Comment: 50 seconds is a lot of time, I said that it's lock the UI very long time, because I need wait to the answer from this function, don't you have another idia?Thank you!

Comment: you can decrease it to 5 sec its up to you , I will edit it

Comment: so the solution is to use socket? what about the port is it changes betweent the remote or local server?

Comment: this method just to check server is on or not , as your requirement , if you want ping local server check what port you connected to it

Comment: An `IOException` in the above code does not indicate a 'sudden disconnection'. There is no connection to be disconnected.

Comment: @user5912232 You didn't understand whose meaning?